# Could not find builder-3.0.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I've been [using](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) on my server [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) 1.1.x for some time and I'm trying to upgrade it to 2.2.2. I followed the [upgrade sequence](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade) and now the application is not working anymore :

`'block in materialize': Could not find builder-3.0.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`

However:

```
bicou@ssh:~/redmine-2.2.2$ bundle install
Using rake (10.0.3)
Using i18n (0.6.1)
Using multi_json (1.5.0)
Using activesupport (3.2.11)
Using builder (3.0.0)
Using activemodel (3.2.11)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.4)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.2.2)
Using actionpack (3.2.11)
Using mime-types (1.19)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.12)
Using mail (2.4.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.11)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.35)
Using activerecord (3.2.11)
Using activeresource (3.2.11)
Using coderay (1.0.8)
Using fastercsv (1.5.5)
Using icalendar (1.2.1)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Using json (1.7.6)
Using rdoc (3.12)
Using thor (0.16.0)
Using railties (3.2.11)
Using jquery-rails (2.0.3)
Using metaclass (0.0.1)
Using mocha (0.12.3)
Using mysql (2.8.1)
Using net-ldap (0.3.1)
Using pg (0.14.1)
Using ruby-openid (2.1.8)
Using rack-openid (1.3.1)
Using bundler (1.2.3)
Using rails (3.2.11)
Using rmagick (2.13.1)
Using shoulda (2.11.3)
Using sqlite3 (1.3.7)
Using yard (0.8.3)
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
bicou@ssh:~/redmine-2.2.2$ bundle show builder
/home/bicou/gems/gems/builder-3.0.0
bicou@ssh:~/redmine-2.2.2$ env | grep gem
GEM_HOME=/home/bicou/gems/
PATH=/home/bicou/gems/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games
GEM_PATH=/home/bicou/gems/
```

As you can see, builder v3.0.0 *is* installed. What gives?

What I did try:

- remove Gemfile.lock and run `bundle install` again
- what Paulo Fidalgo advised (see below)

**Based on Paulo Fidalgo advice:**

My Gemfile contains builder 3.0.0:

```
bicou@ssh:~/redmine-2.2.2$ grep builder Gemfile
gem "builder", "3.0.0"
bicou@ssh:~/redmine-2.2.2$ bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (10.0.3)
Using i18n (0.6.1)
Using multi_json (1.5.0)
Using activesupport (3.2.11)
Using builder (3.0.0)
Using activemodel (3.2.11)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.4)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.2.2)
Using actionpack (3.2.11)
Using mime-types (1.19)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.12)
Using mail (2.4.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.11)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.35)
Using activerecord (3.2.11)
Using activeresource (3.2.11)
Using bundler (1.2.3)
Using coderay (1.0.8)
Using fastercsv (1.5.5)
Using icalendar (1.2.1)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Using json (1.7.6)
Using rdoc (3.12)
Using thor (0.16.0)
Using railties (3.2.11)
Using jquery-rails (2.0.3)
Using metaclass (0.0.1)
Using mocha (0.12.3)
Using mysql (2.8.1)
Using net-ldap (0.3.1)
Using pg (0.14.1)
Using ruby-openid (2.1.8)
Using rack-openid (1.3.1)
Using rails (3.2.11)
Using rmagick (2.13.1)
Using shoulda (2.11.3)
Using sqlite3 (1.3.7)
Using yard (0.8.3)
Your bundle is updated! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
bicou@ssh:~/redmine-2.2.2$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had several issues (for example some gems compiled with a different ruby version than the runtime), but the main one was that my web host requires me to install gems into `~/gems` and hence to export `GEMS_PATH = ~/gems/`!

That, in my `public/.htaccess`, fixed the main issue:

```
SetEnv GEM_PATH /home/bicou/gems/
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add builder to your Gemfile and then run:

> bundle update

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations. I have edited my question. As you can see builder was already in my gemfile, and even after a `bundle update` I still have the same problem with the same error message.

Comment: Can you provide the instructions you are following? Are you using rvm or gemsets? The error happens when you run rails s or are you using phusion passenger?

Comment: Sure. Please review the latest edit to my post with links to the software website and upgrade instructions.